# OSGi AspectService get Service Properties of the Aspected Service

Tags: java, osgi, felix-dependency-manager

Given a service `Sender` with properties, and an aspect service `LogSender`, how does `LogSender` get the service properties of the current `Sender`? I'd like to add a property to optionally log the data that a specific `Sender` is sending.

`component.getServiceProperties();` seems to return the `LogSender`'s service properties instead of `Sender`'s properties.

I've looked at `ConfigAdmin` but I don't see a way to associate the `Sender` that `LogSender` aspected, with the specific configuration used.

I'm using Apache Felix as my OSGi container if that's relevant.

Here's the `Activator`'s `init` method after adding `ConfigurationAdmin` to the dependency list.

```
public void init(BundleContext context, DependencyManager manager) throws Exception {
     manager.add(createAspectService(Sender.class, null, 10).setImplementation(LogSender.class)
            .add(createServiceDependency().setService(ConfigurationAdmin.class)
                    .setRequired(true)));
            .add(createServiceDependency().setService(LogService.class).setRequired(true)));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To inject the service properties of the original Sender into the LogSender aspect, you can use the signature in DependencyActivatorBase (or DependencyManager), which allows to specify "add/change/remove" LogSender aspect callback methods:

```
DependencyActivatorBase.createAspectService(
    Class<?> serviceInterface,
    String serviceFilter,
    int ranking,
    String add,
    String change,
    String remove);
```

Then the LogSenderAspect callbacks method signature can take as arguments the Sender service, as well as the Sender service properties Map.

Now, the second (simpler) solution is to specify a service filter for your aspect, and in this case; no need to specify any callbacks.

let's take a look at the first solution with callbacks, where the LogSender aspect defines a "setSender(Sender, Map)" method, and the aspect will then only log the "send" method of Sender services having "foo=bar" service properties (here, we ignore service change/removed callbacks):

```
public class Activator extends DependencyActivatorBase{
    public void init(BundleContext ctx, DependencyManager dm) throws Exception {
        Component logSender = createAspectService(Sender.class, null, 10, "setSender", null, null)
                .setImplementation(LogSender.class)    
                .add(createServiceDependency().setService(LogService.class).setRequired(true));
        dm.add(logSender);         
    }
}

class LogSender implements Sender {     
    volatile Sender sender;
    volatile Map<String, Object> senderProperties;
    volatile LogService log;

    void setSender(Sender sender, Map<String, Object> senderProperties) {
        this.sender = sender;
        this.senderProperties = senderProperties;
    }

    @Override
    public void send() {
        if ("bar".equals(senderProperties.get("foo"))) {
            log.log(LogService.LOG_DEBUG, "calling method send called on Sender service having properties foo=bar");
        }
        this.sender.send();         
    }       
}
```

Now, a simpler solution consists in using a service filter "(foo=bar)" when defining your aspect, and in this case, no need to use callback:

```
public class Activator extends DependencyActivatorBase{
    public void init(BundleContext ctx, DependencyManager dm) throws Exception {
        Component logSender = createAspectService(Sender.class, "(foo=bar)", 10)
                .setImplementation(LogSender.class)    
                .add(createServiceDependency().setService(LogService.class).setRequired(true));
        dm.add(logSender);         
    }
}

class LogSender implements Sender {     
    volatile Sender sender;

    @Override
    public void send() {
        log.log(LogService.LOG_DEBUG, "calling method send called on Sender service having properties foo=bar");
        this.sender.send();
    }       
}
```

does this help ?
/Pierre

Comment: I swear I tried the three argument callback version and didn't get it to work, and the only thing I thought was different was I used `Dictionary<String, Object>` instead of `Map<String, Object>` but trying it again just now shows it works either way. I don't know what I did differently earlier, but the important thing is it's working now.